# Awk of string followed by '\n'

Tags: text-processing, awk, grep, newlines

I try to parse a plain text config file `A.conf` with the following content:

```
bitrate 500000
use_can 1
```

I want to use the number behind `bitrate` to setup a CAN-interface with the appropriate bitrate.
Here is the corresponding part of my shell script:

```
bitrate="$(cat /home/pi/A.conf | grep 'bitrate' | awk '{print $2}')"
sudo /sbin/ip link set can0 up type can bitrate $bitrate
```

It works fine, if there is at least one empty space character after the number `500000`, but not if it is immediately followed by a newline. 
In that case I get this error output:

```
" is wrong: invalid "bitrate" value
```

What is the reason for this behaviour and how can I fix it? I don't want to rely on the fact that each config file needs empty space characters before each new line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your input file apparently contains a DOS carriage return (ctrl-M, octal `\015`).  The sane solution is not not use a Windows editor in the first place; a reasonable workaround is to explicitly remove this character.

```
bitrate="$(tr -d '\015' < /home/pi/A.conf | awk '/bitrate/ {print $2}')"
```

Notice also how this does away with the useless `cat` and the useless `grep`.

Comment: Without `tr`: `bitrate="$(</home/pi/A.conf awk -F '[ \r]' '/bitrate/ {print $2}')"`

Comment: Yeah, though the really proper solution is to not have this stupid character in the file in the first place.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! Both solutions are working perfectly. Unfortunately, I will have to deal with the DOS carriage return, because the config file is created on a Windows machine and downloaded to the Raspberry Pi from the cloud.

Comment: It would be more natural imho to set the record separator to DOS style (e.g. `-vRS='\r\n'`) rather than adding `\r` as a field separator. If you *do* change `FS`, I'd recommend making it `[ \t\r]+` to preserve the default behavior of splitting on one or more whitespace characters.

Comment: Many Windows editors are perfectly capable of producing valid Unix text files, and many upload tools are able to perform line-ending translation when you upload a text file.

Comment: Maybe `awk '/bitrate/ {gsub(/\r/,"");print $2}' < /home/pi/A.conf` (to avoid calling two programs instead of only one).